# Condition inside Ext JS 4.1 GroupHeaderTpl

Tags: grid, extjs4, grouping, extjs4.1

I need to change groupHeaderTpl upon to the groupingField value. In my case, I group through a boolean field.
How can I do this?

```
groupHeaderTpl: '{name}=="true" ? Shared : Your own'

groupHeaderTpl: '[{name}=="true" ? Shared : Your own]'
```

Answer (score 3):

If the below answer doesn't help you, here's a technique you could use to debug:

Introduce a debugging function "objectToString" in your page:

```
function ObjectToString(object) {
    var string;
    var name;

    for (name in object) {
        if (typeof object[name] !== 'function') {
            string += "{\"" + name + "\": \"" + object[name] + "\"}<br />";
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Then, use this function to dump out the attributes in the values.rows[0] object so you can see if the columns / values you want are available for the test:

```
var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
groupHeaderTpl: 'Debug: {[ObjectToString( values.rows[0] ) ]}',
    hideGroupedHeader: true
});
```

When this is used to debug the example below, you can get this debugging output:

[image: Example of debugging output]

So, from this you can see that by setting the "id" property of the column I'm grouping on, that makes the column name available in the values.rows array so I can test its value.

Again, hope this technique and the below original sample helps.

==== Original Example Below Before Debugging Code ====

Here's a sample modified slightly from the Sencha grid grouping example.  (See [sencha site, grid grouping example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/groupgrid.html)).

```
var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
groupHeaderTpl: 'Cuisine: {[ values.rows[0].cuisine == "American" ? "North American" : values.rows[0].cuisine ]}',
    hideGroupedHeader: true
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    collapsible: true,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    frame: true,
    store: Restaurants,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Restaurants',
    resizable: true,
    features: [groupingFeature],
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'name'
    },{
        text: 'Cuisine',
        id: 'cuisine',    // NOTE: you must assign an id here
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'cuisine'
    }],
    fbar  : ['->', {
        text:'Clear Grouping',
        iconCls: 'icon-clear-group',
        handler : function(){
            groupingFeature.disable();
        }
    }]
});
```

The things to keep in mind are:

1. Set the "id" attribute in the column definitions or you won't be able to reference those columns in the groupHeaderTpl
2. Use {[ ... ]} in the groupHeaderTpl to run some arbitrary javascript to perform your checks
3. Use value.rows[0].FIELDNAME to pull out the column value you want from the first row in the group

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I think that we can't use `values.row[n].field` to test statements. Because value of field always changes.. The grouping feature gives us the grouping field value by `{name}` variable. All we need is creating a valid tpl to test it. I tried this one `groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ? "Shared Documents" : "Your Documents"'` but it didn't work at all..

Comment: Note that all the rows in the group will have the same value for values.row[n].field if they are grouped by "field", so it *is* OK to use values.row[0].field for the field they are grouped on.  The reason you want to use values.row[n].field instead of {name} is that inside the {[ ... ]} brackets, {name} isn't available.  And, you need the {[ ... ]} brackets to be able to use tests like if and "?" ternary operator.

Comment: `shared` is my grouping field which is a boolean field. I've done this before: `groupHeaderTpl: '{[values.rows[0].shared ? "Shared Documents" : "Your Documents"]}''` But this didn't work too.. It's always rendering "Your Documents". Also I tried string comparison which didn't work too..

Comment: One possible source of problems -- did you set the "id" attribute of the shared column?  If you don't set the id of the column, it will get a generated ID and you won't be able to access its value via "values[0].shared".  See the code example above where the grouped by column, with dataIndex "cuisine" has its id set to "cuisine" also so that it will be available as "values[0].cuisine" in the group header template.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try the following:

```
groupHeaderTpl: '{[values.groupValue ? "Shared" : "Your own"]}'
```

This works for me with Ext JS 4.2 (although I haven't verified it with 4.1, the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-groupHeaderTpl) also describes groupValue).

HTH